# Is there a way to bind constructor parameters without annotations with Guice?

Tags: guice

With ninject for .net it is simple, example:

```
Bind<Interface>().To<InterfaceImpl>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("parameterName", value);
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with Guice?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings):

```
public class BillingModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override 
  protected void configure() {
    try {
      bind(TransactionLog.class).toConstructor(
          DatabaseTransactionLog.class.getConstructor(DatabaseConnection.class));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      addError(e);
    }
  }
}
```

For your case, replace `try` block with next:

```
bind(Interface.class)
  .toConstructor(InterfaceImpl.class.getConstructor(Param1.class, Param2.class));
```

Comment: Where do you specify the constructor parameters as per my example above?

Comment: Can you replace DatabaseConnection.class, if it is a string? Inserting "somestringinstead"

Comment: @FritzSeitz You need to tell Guice which constructor he need to use, so as a parameter you need to send him reference to the constructor ([constructor signature](http://tcljava.sourceforge.net/docs/TclJava/JavaSignatures.html)). 
`InterfaceImpl.class.getConstructor(Param1.class, Param2.class)`, where `Param1..n` are **arguments type**